# How to construct a layered 3D graph of three community structures?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, code-request

Consider:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

select[matrix_, lB_, uB_] := 
  matrix*Map[Boole[lB <= # < uB] &, matrix, {-1}];

SeedRandom[131];
mm = RandomReal[1, {15, 15}]*
   RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[.3], {15, 15}];
g = SimpleGraph[WeightedAdjacencyGraph[mm /. {0. -> Infinity}]];
com = CommunityGraphPlot[g, VertexLabels -> "Name"];

mL = select[mm, 0, .2];
gL = SimpleGraph[WeightedAdjacencyGraph[mL /. {0. -> Infinity}]];
comL = CommunityGraphPlot[gL, VertexLabels -> "Name"];

mM = select[mm, .3, .7];
gM = SimpleGraph[WeightedAdjacencyGraph[mM /. {0. -> Infinity}]];
comM = CommunityGraphPlot[gM, VertexLabels -> "Name"];

mH = select[mm, .7, 1];
gH = SimpleGraph[WeightedAdjacencyGraph[mH /. {0. -> Infinity}]];
comH = CommunityGraphPlot[gH, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
```

It generates three community structures: one for LOW values `comL`, one for MEDIUM values `comM`, and one for HIGH values `comH` of matrix `mm`.

How can I combine these three community structures in a single `LayeredGraphPlot3D[...]` with three layers. Each layer should have a single community structure such as `comH`. The bottom layer of this 3D plot should have `comL`, the medium layer `comM`, and the top layer `comH`.

I also like to have flexibility to link these three layers with edges of my choice. For example, I should be able to draw a directed edge from community 1 in the bottom layer to community 3 at the top layer. Since the linkages between communities across layers are not identified yet, I like to define the linkages as a separate rule in the code.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I like to have a layered plot shown in the following figure, with community structures placed on each layer. With this figure, I will be able to link community structures at each layer. Field B in the figure will be community structure `comH`, and Field A with `comM` and then Field C with `comL`.

[image]